# Changing date object from "%Y/%m/%d" to "%d/%m/%Y" in R

Tags: r

How do I change the format of the `date object` from `"%Y/%m/%d"` to `"%d/%m/%Y"`. I have tried the `below-mentioned code` without much success.

```
as.Date(bank$date,format="%d/%m/%Y")
      [1] "2007-11-02" "2007-11-09" "2007-11-16" "2007-11-23" "2007-11-30" "2007-12-07"
      [7] "2007-12-14" "2007-12-20" "2007-12-28" "2008-01-04" "2008-01-11" "2008-01-18"
     [13] "2008-01-25" "2008-02-01" "2008-02-08" "2008-02-15" "2008-02-22" "2008-02-29"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Date class has a fixed format in R which is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Any other format will be character.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah for the clarification. My issue is  I am using the package `SystemicR` to calculate covar and getting this error message - 'Error in as.Date.default(df_data_returns[2:Number_Observations, 1], "%d/%m/%Y") : do not know how to convert 'df_data_returns[2:Number_Observations, 1]' to class “Date”. Can you help with the error msg. Thanks.

Comment: which function in `SystemicR` are you using?

Comment: Maybe `SystemicR` is not expecting a `Date` object but a `character` with the format `%d/%m/%Y` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
date <- as.Date("2007-11-02")
new_date <- format(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
new_date
#> [1] "02/11/2007"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @Desmond. The `new_date` is now a `character`. I want the `new_date` to be the `date' class object.

Comment: that's simply not possible -- perhaps you can elaborate on why you think you need a date object in this format?

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I am using the package `SystemicR` to calculate covar and getting this error message - 'Error in as.Date.default(df_data_returns[2:Number_Observations, 1], "%d/%m/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'df_data_returns[2:Number_Observations, 1]' to class “Date”'. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with the data, libraries, your code and the error you're getting .